# Adding native validation to Vue Headless UI Listbox (Select) component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, headless-ui

I am trying to add Native validation support to Vue3 or Nuxt 3 Vue Headless UI Listbox (Select) component. As per my understanding its not directly supported so I would like to know which is the best and easy way.

Can you please guide me on how to adopt native validation to ListBox?

DropDown.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-col items-center">
    <label class="w-1/6 pb-1 text-sm font-semibold">{{ label }}</label>
    <Listbox
      v-model="item"
      @update:modelValue="onItemChange"
      :required="required"
      :default-value="defaultSelectionRef"
    >
      <div class="relative z-10 w-full">
        <ListboxButton
          class="dropdown relative w-full pl-3 text-sm text-left sm:text-sm rounded h-12 border border-gray-300 dark:border-slate-700 dark:bg-slate-700 dark:hover:bg-slate-600"
          :required="required"
        >
          <span class="block truncate dark:text-white">{{ item.text }}</span>
          <span
            class="pointer-events-none absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2"
          >
            <Icon icon="fe:arrow-down" />
          </span>
        </ListboxButton>
        <transition
          leave-active-class="transition duration-100 ease-in"
          leave-from-class="opacity-100"
          leave-to-class="opacity-0"
        >
          <ListboxOptions
            class="absolute mt-1 w-full overflow-auto rounded shadow-md bg-white py-1 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm dark:bg-slate-800 dark:text-white"
            :required="required"
          >
            <ListboxOption
              v-slot="{ active }"
              v-for="option in options"
              :key="option.value"
              :value="option"
              as="template"
              :disabled="option.disabled"
              :required="required"
            >
              <li
                :class="[
                  active ? 'bg-[#E5F0FC] dark:bg-slate-700' : '',
                  'relative select-none py-2 pl-4 pr-4 cursor-pointer',
                ]"
                :required="required"
              >
                <span :class="option.class">{{ option.text }}</span>
              </li>
            </ListboxOption>
          </ListboxOptions>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </Listbox>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Icon } from "@iconify/vue";
import {
  Listbox,
  ListboxButton,
  ListboxOptions,
  ListboxOption,
} from "@headlessui/vue";

const props = defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String, // label for the dropdown field
    required: false,
  },
  defaultSelection: {
    type: Object, // default selected item in drop down
    required: false,
  },
  options: {
    type: Array, // array of options in the drop down
    required: true,
  },
  required: {
    type: Boolean, // condition based on which dropdown becomes required or not
    required: false,
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: [String, Number, Object, null], // name of the corresponding model for dropdown field
    required: false,
  },
});

const defaultSelectionRef = computed(() => {
  //Get existing model value for the dropdown
  const modelValue = props.modelValue;

  //If there is no existing value return 1st element of dropdown options array
  if (modelValue === undefined || modelValue === null) {
    return props.options[0];
  }

  //If there is existing value then return matching element from options array
  return (
    props.options.find((obj) => obj.value === modelValue) ||
    props.options.find((obj) => obj.value === modelValue.value)
  );
});

const item = ref(defaultSelectionRef.value);

const emits = defineEmits(["onItemChange", "update:modelValue"]);

watch(defaultSelectionRef, (newValue) => {
  item.value = newValue;
});

// Emit the updated modelValue when the selectedOption changes
watchEffect(() => {
  emits("update:modelValue", item.value.value);
});

const onItemChange = () => {
  emits("onItemChange", props.model, item.value);
};
</script>
```

Usage in pages/test.vue:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <div class="overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
        <table class="w-full text-sm dark:text-white">
          <caption />
          <th id="tableHeader" />
          <tbody>
            <tr class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
              <td
                class="px-4 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-center bg-gray-500 text-white dark:text-black"
              >
                <DropDown
                  v-model="formData.type"
                  :label="$t('pages.modal.select-type')"
                  :options="options"
                  :required="true"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  
      <button
        type="submit"
        class="mt-2 mb-2 text-green-700 border-green-700 focus:ring-green-300 hover:bg-green-700 dark:hover:bg-green-500 dark:focus:ring-green-800 dark:border-green-500 dark:text-green-500 block rounded-full hover:text-white border focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:hover:text-white"
      >
        {{ $t("pages.modal.submit") }}
      </button>
    </form>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  //Import static values for dropdowns
  import {
    options,
  } from "~/public/Static/DefaultValues";
  const formData = ref({});
  
  const submitForm = async (event) => {
    console.log("Form submitted successfully");
  };
  </script>
  
  <style>
  </style>
```

I want to prevent the form from being submitted if the user has not selected the value. I am trying to figure out a direct approach to see if I can directly validate and show native message. I know it can be done by some additional methods and coding but trying to avoid it as much as possible and finding best and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented a bit only functional omitting some styling and arrived at this result. In my opinion, this is the simplest solution to validate the select box directly and display a message if nothing has been selected. Of course, a validation framework e.g. [VeeValidate](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/) would be much more flexible, but I believe this should suffice.

**Defined component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <label>{{ label }}</label>
    <Listbox v-model="inputValue" :defaultValue="options[0]">
      <div ref="target">
        <ListboxButton
          v-slot="{ value }" 
          @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
        >
          <span v-if="inputValue" class="block truncate dark:text-white">{{ value }}</span>
          <span v-else class="block truncate dark:text-white">Choose an option</span>
        </ListboxButton>
        <ListboxOptions>
          <ListboxOption
            as="template"
            v-slot="{ active }"
            v-for="option in options"
            :key="option.id"
            :value="option.name"
            :disabled="option.unavailable"
          >
            <li :class="[active ? 'bg-[#E5F0FC] dark:bg-slate-700' : '']">
              <span>{{ option.name }}</span>
            </li>
          </ListboxOption>
        </ListboxOptions>
      </div>
    </Listbox>
    <div v-if="showError" class="text-red-500">
      <strong>Please select something</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import {
  Listbox,
  ListboxButton,
  ListboxOptions,
  ListboxOption,
} from '@headlessui/vue';

const props = defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String,
  },
  options: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  required: {
    type: Boolean,
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: [String, Number, Object, null],
  },
});

const emits = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
const showError = ref(false)
const isOpen = ref(false)
const target = ref(null)

const inputValue = computed({
    get() {
        return props.modelValue
    },
    set(value) {
        emits('update:modelValue', value)
    }
})

// This method can be handled also within a custom directive
function handleClickOutside(event) {
  if (!target.value.contains(event.target) && isOpen.value && props.required) {
    showError.value = !inputValue.value
  } else if (inputValue.value) {
    showError.value = false
  }
}
 
onMounted(() => {
  document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
})
</script>
```

**Use component:**

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <DropDown
      v-model="optionValue"
      :label="'Label XYZ'"
      :options="options"
      :required="true"
    />

    <button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import DropDown from '../components/DropDown.vue'

const options = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Durward Reynolds', unavailable: false },
  { id: 2, name: 'Kenton Towne', unavailable: false },
  { id: 3, name: 'Therese Wunsch', unavailable: false },
  { id: 4, name: 'Benedict Kessler', unavailable: true },
  { id: 5, name: 'Katelyn Rohan', unavailable: false },
]

const optionValue = ref(null)

const submitForm = async (event) => {
  // Implement some logic before submitting
  console.log("Form submitted successfully")
}
</script>
```

I hope the code is self-explanatory enough and was able to assist you.